# What's the point of naming Iptables' tables as "tables"?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, iptables, terminology

After reading some guides (e.g. [this one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/iptables)) and playing with Iptables tuning I found that I see no reason for naming Iptables' tables as tables.
I mean that there practically are no tables.
E.g. having "table" `nat` there are basically three chains in it - `PREROUTING`, `OUTPUT` and `POSTROUTING`, but these chains in this table have no intersections and do not follow each other directly. So from the [packet flow](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg)'s point of view **highlighting the concept of tables doesn't make any sense at all**.
The name of "**table**" (`raw`, `filter`, `nat`, `mangle`, `security`, ...) just **represents a priority** of groups of rules inside chains and also some other properties (e.g. `nat` group of rules work just once per-connection, `filter` work per-packet and so on).

Thus it should be not "table contains several chains" but something like "chain contains groups of rules with specific global priority (and some other common properties)". Doesn't it?

Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: "The name of "table" just represents a priority of groups of rules inside chains" -- do you mean the fact that e.g. the `PREROUTING` chains of `raw`, `mangle` and `nat` tables are  processed at around the the same time, in a particular order? AFAIU, it's not just the order though, but tables _do_ do different things. e.g. you can't use `SNAT` in the `filter` table. How much that is just about splitting different kinds of decisions to different places, and how much relates to other stuff the code does, I don't know. (then again, IIRC, e.g. the `nat` table is only checked for new connections.)

Comment: Anyway, I'm not exactly sure if it's just the name "table", you're questioning, or the fact that there _are_ multiple different tables (with chains of the same name), regardless of the name chosen?

Comment: @ilkkachu *"do you mean the fact that e.g. the PREROUTING chains of raw, mangle and nat tables are processed at around the the same time, in a particular order?"* - yep. *"tables do do different things. e.g. you can't use SNAT in the filter table"* - doesn't it just a priority issue? It seems that **we can just have several global priorities which can be applied or not to specific chain**.

Comment: I totally agree with you. The terms are really confusing. I guess, from designer's perspective, `chains` are containers of rules, and `tables` are for different usages.  But for newbie of this tool, like me, I assume `tables` are container and `chains` are channels. That's cause the difficulties  to understand.  it's more straightforward if `chains` could be named as `tables`, and `tables` could be renamed to `tag`, `priority`, `channel`, `group` or a clear concept.

Comment: I am a newbie to iptables and spent 2 weeks on it due to the confusing names.

Answer (score 1):

The name tables is of historical origin:

- Once, there were simple rules.
- Then, there were ipchains - rules could have been chained.
- A major rewrite of all the firewalling system resulted in a filter, that kept a table of states for all connections (and connection-like thinks like upd request and appropriate answer). Hence the 'table' name. And also rules for different parts of the process of a packet traversing one of paths (e. g. a packet for our system, that shall be received) can be organized into a few tables of rules (INPUT, FORWARD, OUTPUT, PREROUTING, POSTROUTING).

A history summarized above is swiftly describe here: https://netfilter.org/about.html#history.

Comment: *"rules...can be organized into a few tables of rules (INPUT, FORWARD, OUTPUT, PREROUTING, POSTROUTING)"* - didn't get it. INPUT, FORWARD, OUTPUT, PREROUTING, POSTROUTING are **chains**. What do you mean?

Comment: If you try to imagine, what's going on, it helps (at least to some of us) to see the filtering process as a few "checklists". If you plan to start an airplane, you first need to pickup proper checklist (basically pieces of paper) and go through them. Similarly when you are receiving a packet, the packet need to go through some "papers" with some inspection rules on them. If it passes them all, it's accepted and processed.

Comment: "a table of states for all connections" -- isn't that conntrack? It's not like the states of connections are in the iptables tables, right? (Also, `INPUT`, `FORWARD` etc. are chains, not tables.)

Comment: @ikkachu Yes, it's conntrack. In old times of ipchains, connections were not tracked.

Comment: @d.c. *"If it passes them all, it's accepted and processed"* - nope. It can be accepted and "processed"(whatever that means) even when it pass just several of them, e.g. `PREROUTING` and `INPUT`.
*"try to imagine"* - I don't need, because I know the packet traversal through the Linux kernel network stack. But I still don't understand the concept of tables.
Also I still don't understand why are you calling *"INPUT, FORWARD, OUTPUT, PREROUTING, POSTROUTING"* tables while these are chains?

Comment: Btw not my downvote.